# Как и чем лучше заменить "на всех парах", обозначив состояние боевой готовности?

Tags: синонимы, идиомы

> На стоянке нас уже поджидали две машины эскорта, да на всех парах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**На стоянке нас уже поджидали две машины эскорта...**

готовых мчаться на всех парах;
готовых моментально (в любой момент, в любую секунду) сорваться с места;
— наготове, словно под парами.

Answer (score 3):

"На всех парах" можно только "нестись", стоять на месте придётся как-нибудь "вовсю пыхтя (выхлопами)" или "полностью раскочегаренными".

Answer (score 1):

*На стоянке нас уже поджидали две машины эскорта, **готовые немедленно отправиться в путь.***

Здесь скорее (или возможно) обозначена готовность к движению, а не желание мчаться на всех порах.

Куда спешить-то?

Comment: Вы уверены, что "готовых", а не "готовые"?

Comment: Спасибо, ответ исправлен.

Answer (score 0):

По мне так менять ничего не надо, разве только предлог.
***"Под всеми парами".***
Моряки подвердят, что они и ходят и стоят именно "под парами".

Даже если допустить, что двигаться можно только "на" (что сомнитьельно), то уж стоять-то "под" никто не запрещал?!

> Корвет стоял под парами и был готов к немедленному отплытию.
>
> При виде корвета, идущего под всеми парами, с обломанным бушпритом и
> поврежденной мачтой, жители города заволновались,

(Верн Ж. "Вокруг Луны". пер. М. Виленская)